# Plugin for an author bio popup box?

Tags: author

Looking at the below article, I took a liking to the way the author included his bio (as a clickable little bio box that pops up).

http://saveyourself.ca/articles/why-does-pain-hurt-so-much.php

Does anybody know where I could find a plugin to do such a thing? All the plugins I've found are for sticking bios at the end of posts, in widgets, hovering over the name, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Wordpress Author Pop-up plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/author-popup/).

> This plugin does the same thing as the the_author tag, displays the
>   author name, only this time it's linked to hidden layer (div). By
>   clicking on the author link the hidden layer(div) pop's up with author
>   info gathered from the profile page, plus gravatar photo (if author
>   email is assigned with one) & social links from profile custom fields.

Comment: In case anyone ends up here looking for a solution... It's worth noting that the above plugin hasn't been updated for 5yrs now.